# LibGDX set size of FBO

Tags: libgdx

Is there any way to set the size of the FBO?

My device has an 1200*800 pixel, but I want to create only a 600*400 or, 300*200, or 150*100 pixel size FBO, any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FBOs are `FrameBuffer` in LibGDX. The constructor takes the size of the FBO.

```
new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, 600, 400, true);
```